# (Vue + Laravel) How to update an object from axios response data and use it in another function?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, undefined

I'm stuck in my ToDo App where I want to add a progress Bar for the completed tasks.

The `response.data` is in a `nodelist` like so:

```
[
  {"id":21,"title":"Third","completed":0,"created_at":"2020-11-17T14:45:08.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-11-17T16:10:29.000000Z"},
  {"id":24,"title":"fourth","completed":0,"created_at":"2020-11-17T20:51:02.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-11-17T20:51:02.000000Z"},
  {"id":18,"title":"First ToDo","completed":1,"created_at":"2020-11-17T13:31:14.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-11-17T16:49:14.000000Z"},
  {"id":19,"title":"Second ToDo","completed":1,"created_at":"2020-11-17T14:11:17.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-11-17T20:23:21.000000Z"}
]`
```

I defined tasks in data in my `TaskComponent.vue`:

```js
    data(){

        return{
            hook: '',
            editmode: false,
            // todos: [],
            todos: {
                title: '',
                completed: '',
```

and get the response data from the database using laravel:

```js
    getTask(){
            axios.get('api/task').then(function(res) {
                this.todos = res.data;
            }.bind(this)).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error);
            })
        },
```

then I want to use this fetched data to count my completed and total tasks and get the percentage of it

```js
    computed: {     
           checkCompleted(){
            let count = 0;           
            for (let i = 0; i < this.todos.length; ++i){
                if(this.todos[i]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
```

Problem is, that the `todos` object doesn't update and keeps being empty. The value of `this.todos` is still empty.
I can't get it why I can use the `todos` object with its data in the `<template>` and not in another function.

```
<template>
   <div v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
       <span v-if="editmode == false || editmode != todo.id">{{todo.title}}</span>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I would sugest to minimize your code: Just try to have one piece of data in "data" and display that. Does this work?

Comment: You defined 'todos' in data as an object, not an array. You can't use `this.todos.length`, becouse it will be `undefined`. Have you tried to define todos as empty array? `todos: []`?

Comment: I tried to define todos as an array [] and it didn't work either
but I am now one step further: I figured out that you can only use the updated objects from axios.get in the <template>. In order to use it in the <script> you have to use Vuex and mount it to the main App.vue like in this example:

https://github.com/lizzz0523/limni/tree/master/todo-app